# Changing a Field Set programmatically in Apex

Tags: apex, fieldsets

Is it possible to update/edit a field set from Apex programmatically?

We have a javascript app that connects to an Apex back end. 
If possible, we want an admin to be able to update the field set we use for displaying our object directly from the app itself, but I cant find anything about doing that so I dont know if its possible

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the post added as a comment, Its possible through Metadata API.

In your scenario, you should explore either Custom Setting or Metatdata Types as the performance would be better with it.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the link. That seems part of what I need. I have existing field sets that were created on a specific object. How can I get them field sets and update an existing one? The link just mentions making a new field set and then updating one you just created. Cheers

Comment: That is kind of trial and error, sometimes you just need to try until you get desired output. Please check let us know if you face any specific issues. would be happy to help!